# async await javascript for merge sort visualization

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
        function sleep(ms) { // new code: checkout a video about promises
             return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        }


    async function mergeDraw(anArray,startPoint){
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            j = startPoint;

            for(num = 0; num < anArray.length; num++){
                anArray[num][1] = j;

                ctx.lineWidth = 3.2 ;
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'seagreen'
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(j, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(j, 800);
                ctx.stroke();

                ctx.lineWidth = 3;
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
                ctx.beginPath(); 
                ctx.moveTo(j, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(j, anArray[num][0]);
                ctx.stroke();

                j+=8;
            }
            await sleep(10);
    }
        
        function merger(arr1, arr2) {

          let i = 0,j = 0,mergedArr = [];
          while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {

            if (arr1[i][0] > arr2[j][0]){

                mergedArr.push(arr2[j]);
                j++;
            } else{
                mergedArr.push(arr1[i]);
                i++;
            }

          }
          while (i < arr1.length) {
            mergedArr.push(arr1[i]);
            i++;
          }
          while (j < arr2.length) {
            mergedArr.push(arr2[j]);
            j++;
          }


          var lowest = mergedArr[0][1];
          for( num = 1; num < mergedArr.length; num++){
            if(mergedArr[num][1] < lowest){
                lowest = mergedArr[num][1];
            }
          }
          
          mergeDraw(mergedArr, lowest);

          return mergedArr;
        }



        function mergeSort(array) {

          //Array of length 1 is sorted so we return the same array back
          if (array.length == 1) return array;

          //Break down the array to half from middle into left and right
          let middle = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
          let left = mergeSort(array.slice(0, middle));
          let right = mergeSort(array.slice(middle));

          //Return the merged sorted array
          return merger(left, right);
        }
```

I am trying to make a visualization for mergeSort. My mergeSort function divides my bigger array into smaller arrays. These smaller arrays are then sorted into the mergeArr array by the merger function. The mergeDraw then draws the changes made. I want there to be a small pause after the drawing has been made before the a new mergedArr is drawn. I tried to do this using async await but this doesn't work. Is there a better way to do this instead of using async await?

Comment: try putting  `await sleep(ms)` at start of the function not the end.

Comment: Doing that basically pauses the run for 10 ms then goes on again as if no await exists.

Comment: Is it right to do this with async await or there could be better ways?

Comment: async await is fine, can't think of something better, I am a noob yet.
You can try making merger and mergeSort "async" functions and then await the other async functions you call inside them.